# My laptop in not charging. No indication of power supply either

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, charging

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100 that I bought around 8 months ago. All of a sudden my laptop does not seem to charge. I have dual-booted Linux and Windows and currently  don't have any battery power. I have checked my adapter for power issues and the adapter seems to be fine. Also I guess my motherboard, RAM and video memory are fine since my laptop was working on battery power for some time even after my laptop failed to identify the charger. There used to be a LED indication after I plugged the charger but now that's gone. I can't remove my battery(It will cancel my warranty). Also it is not a overheating problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use the fact it's under warranty and send it back?

Comment: I would do that. But I would like to know what the probable cause is. I would like to solve this problem without much hassle myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the power supply is providing power, It's down to one out of two issues:

- PSU not being able to deliver enough current while the voltage is fine (unlikely)
- Internal charging circuitry in the laptop is busted.

The internal charging circuit usually also works as a powersupply to the components, so if this is broken, this usually manifests itself as being unable to either charging the battery, powering the PC, or both.

This sounds like a warranty-issue.